# Placing Input capacitor of boost after output capacitor

Tags: capacitor, buck, boost, charger, buck-boost

I have a battery charger for 12V input with integrated buck that charges a single cell (3.7V nominal). The charger also has a power path and I would like to place a boost converter to boost the 3.7V to 5V. That means I am chaining a boost converter  after a buck converter (battery charger). How do I select and match the output cap of the buck with the input cap of the boost?

Comment: There was a question almost exactly like yours but worded differently about two weeks ago, but now I can’t find it. Does anyone remember this about one converters output cap plus the downstream converter input cap being shared?

Comment: *That means I am chaining a boost converter after a buck converter (battery charger)* But if I'm understanding this correctly there will be the 3.7 V battery in between. Then due to the battery, you could see the charger (buck) and 3.7 V to 5 V boost converter as individual circuits. Anyway, each converter will need **its own** capacitor as it needs to be **close to the rest of the converter**. Sharing a cap between 2 switched converters is **asking for trouble** in my opinion.

Comment: The real problem is to make sure there is no interaction between the buck output impedance and the negative incremental resistance of the boost converter. It has to be studied in details to be sure the boost open-loop gain is not affected by the buck output impedance. You will find details of the analysis in this APEC 2017 seminar: https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202017.pdf

Comment: Charging a lithium battery with a constant voltage of 3,7V is almost certainly **not** the proper way to charge the battery. You **must** limit the current to the battery for safety. You need a proper charging circuit between the input voltage and the battery.

Comment: yes i know that CCCV will be applied by the charger ;) That's why I wrote 3.7V nominal. also that's not the point of the discussion/question.
Note that battery is connect to system bus via a FET. This will operate in LDO mode if system voltage is higher than battery voltage.
As every converter needs its own capacitor placed closely to the converter: Won't the input capacitor of the boost influence the output capacitor of the buck?